# Design: Business Logic or Data Storage on data manipulation during loads

Tags: database, architecture, storage

I have separated my program between data storage and business logic.

In my database I have two very similar tables, one storing committed updates (many entries per entity), and one entry being a temporary data that I am working on.

This means when I load data the "correct" data is the newest value of either the temporary data or the committed data.

My problem is deciding if providing this information is a "data storage" or a "business logic" problem.

Doing the devils advocate I end up with following 2 claims.

---

**Data Storage issue**

It is up to the data structure to be able to provide the answer to retrieve simple defined data requests, how it is done is the Data Storage. Even if this is done with a mix of code and load of data then this is fine, as long the request is fixed and have a clear answer.

So how this is stored with the temporary information should not be a concern for the Business logic, this means if I later refactor or rework the data structure, the Business logic's request is unaltered. So the solution is to load the newest value from both forms and compare these, and return the newest in defined format

---

**Business Logic issue**

Deciding which data is newest and how its handled is not a Data issue, so code to manipulate data should be placed in the Business Logic, possible via a wrapper (in Business Logic) to avoid having to refactor to much code in case of a change on the data storage. So both results should be requested and compared on the Business Logic side, leaving Data Storage to only maintain retrieval of data.

---

I am leaning heavily toward placing this logic in the Data Storage, as Business logic is asking a simple information and sending a request, that due to other issues this was decided to be stored in a specific way and possible later altered should not impact the Business logic part. So what are your thoughts.

Where would you place the information, and why should Business Logic/Data Storage be used/avoided for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision to have two tables to hold permanent and working data is a data storage one, there being other ways of implementing the concept.  Ideally you should be able to change the data manipulation substrate without having to change the business logic.

Consequently the data storage layer should be responsible for reconciling the implementation and serving up a coherent view of the data.  The best way of achieving this would be with an abstraction such as a view or an API.  Choose whatever approach suits your architecture best.

Comment: If I read this correct, your suggestion is to decide "what is being requested" and let the Data Management side of things handle that deliverable. (its logic, its choice). While leaving Business Logic to handle what needs to be done with that data when loaded? (so the wrapper is placed on the Data Management side so to speak)

Comment: I ended up with saying the handoff was decided 1 result only, and it was the data managers job to cut the stored data down to that 1 result and get it in the right format. In this case I learned about unions when making a query to the database which dropped the result to what I wanted to pull out.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Business Logic layer. (given **your** description above)

The reason you have this Question/dilemma is because you dont use a domain layer .

The business layer should communicate to Data layer using this Domain definition.
If the data layer had split into 2 tables. Then it should combine on retrieval.

So without a Domain or model then what is the "contract" between Data and business layer.
Where is it defined.

Answer the Domain/Model question or where the Contract/Interface is defined. 
Then you you will be nearer your answer.

Recommended reading.  **DDD**
Domain driven design or sometimes called Domain driven development